# Конфликт скриптов

Tags: javascript, lightbox

Здравствуйте. Хотелось бы спросить следующее.
У меня допустим подключено два фреймворка к примеру prototype и lightbox, они разумеется конфликтуют между собой, возможно ли такое как нибудь разрешать например там прменять lightbox только к определенному диву и т.п. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: может воспользоваться <iframe/>

Comment: Не ифраме не охото юзать

Answer (score 2):

Если сами фреймворки не предусматривают какой-то способ избежания конфликтов (Например, в jquery есть такая возможность), то нет возможности что-то с этим поделать. Разве что пытаться вручную править и устранять конфликты, но это совсем не гуд.

Answer (score 1):

`Lightbox` не является фреймворком, это prototype-плагин.

К тому же на сайте производителя `lightbox` указан пример, как использовать фреймворк `prototype` вместе с плагином `lightbox`. Должно работать.

[Пример использования prototype+lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#how)

Какие конфликты у Вас возникают?

Comment: Может я ошибаюсь по поводу лайтбокса, видимо я юзал чтото подобное и у меня не работало,а в данное время у меня конфликтует прототайп и все скрипты которые я нахожу для стилизации Select

Comment: Тогда Вам необходимо найти либо плагин именно для prototype, который стилизуют Select, или же универсальный плагин, к примеру `Chosen`: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/, который поставляется как в `jQuery` версии так и в `Prototype` версии. Если же нужно что-то попроще, можете найти нативно-js-плагин для стилизации Select'a, и быстро проштудировать весь код, убрать перезаписанные методы примитивным типам ( String.prototype.slice ) и т.д. Тогда в нативном коде уже нечему конфликтовать с Prototype

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox так же и для Jquery написан, и это, как сказано выше не фреймворк, и если вы используете соответсвующую версию для вашего фреймворка то конфликтов быть не может... Вам лучше бы сразу описать конфликты...

Comment: Да чего там описывать то, просто работает либо то либо то, я уж отчайился и вместо стилизованного Select делаю див в абсолютным позиционированием и вызываю при нажатии на инпут текстовой, вроде красиво смотрится

Answer (score 0):

Присоединяюсь к [@cy6erGn0m](/users/335/cy6ergn0m), но также добавлю, что можно найти lightbox под prototype и обойтись без jQuery.